# MySQL update with avg for different periods

Tags: mysql

I was hoping I could bake these 3 update queries into one efficient and beautiful query that would update my price table. I know some of you may wonder why I'm even doing this update and not just doing my avg on the fly when I want the data, you can keep wondering.

Query #1 updates the price table with the average price for a pricegroup within 12 months.

Query #2 updates the price table with the average price for a pricegroup within 6 months.

Query #3 updates the price table with the average price for a pricegroup within 3 months.

```
SET
@p12 = '2017-12-01',
@p6 = '2018-06-01',
@p3 = '2018-09-01',
@p1 = '2019-12-01';

/* AVG PRICE 12 MONTHS */
UPDATE
    prices
JOIN product ON
    product.id = prices.product_id
JOIN(
        SELECT
            pricegroup,
            AVG( price ) as avg_price
        FROM
            price_temp
        WHERE
            sales_date BETWEEN @p12 AND @p1
        GROUP BY
            pricegroup
    ) as a ON
    a.pricegroup = product.pricegroup
SET
    prices.price_12 = a.avg_price
WHERE
    prices.`date` = @p1;

/* AVG PRICE 6 MONTHS */
UPDATE
    prices
JOIN product ON
    product.id = prices.product_id
JOIN(
        SELECT
            pricegroup,
            AVG( price ) as avg_price
        FROM
            price_temp
        WHERE
            sales_date BETWEEN @p6 AND @p1
        GROUP BY
            pricegroup
    ) as a ON
    a.pricegroup = product.pricegroup
SET
    prices.price_6 = a.avg_price
WHERE
    prices.`date` = @p1;

/* AVG PRICE 3 MONTHS */
UPDATE
    prices
JOIN product ON
    product.id = prices.product_id
JOIN(
        SELECT
            pricegroup,
            AVG( price ) as avg_price
        FROM
            price_temp
        WHERE
            sales_date BETWEEN @p3 AND @p1
        GROUP BY
            pricegroup
    ) as a ON
    a.pricegroup = product.pricegroup
SET
    prices.price_3 = a.avg_price
WHERE
     prices.`date` = @p1;
```

---- Price table ----

```
| id | product_id | date | price | price_3 | price_6 | price_12 |
```

---- Product table ----

```
| id | pricegroup |
```

---- Prices_temp table ----

```
| pricegroup | sales_date | price |
```

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: So something like "avg(CASE WHEN sales_date BETWEEN p3 AND p1 THEN price END) as avg_p3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking at cases I remade the query and used cases within the AVG

```
UPDATE
    prices
JOIN product ON
    product.id = prices.product_id
JOIN(
        SELECT
            pricegroup,
            avg(CASE WHEN sales_date = @p1 THEN price END) as p1,
            avg(CASE WHEN sales_date BETWEEN @p3 AND @p1 THEN price END) as p3,
            avg(CASE WHEN sales_date BETWEEN @p6 AND @p1 THEN price END) as p6,
            avg(CASE WHEN sales_date BETWEEN @p12 AND @p1 THEN price END) as p12
        FROM
            price_temp
        GROUP BY
            pricegroup
    ) as a ON
    a.pricegroup = product.pricegroup
SET
    prices.price = IF(a.p1 IS NULL, 0, a.p1),
    prices.price_3 = IF(a.p3 IS NULL, 0, a.p3),
    prices.price_6 = IF(a.p6 IS NULL, 0, a.p6),
    prices.price_12 = IF(a.p12 IS NULL, 0, a.p12)
```